# How to override property overflow:hidden for custom tooltip?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I am trying to override property overflow:hidden (parent td element)

[image]

for my tooltip which should be shown under my td element:

Code for tooltip:

```css
.tooltip1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.tooltip1:hover {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip1 span {
  display: none;
}

.tooltip1:hover span {
  border: #666 2px dotted;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: visible !important; //not working
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip1">Link
  <span>CSS tooltip showing up when your mouse over the link</span>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

But I need something like this(tooltip above all cells):

[image]

I need somehow disable or override the property of td **overflow:hidden** for  [.tooltip1:hover span] (our tooltip), so I can't just change if for parent td element.

Comment: paste your `td` element structure content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the tooltip is a child of the td.  If so, you can override the overflow property by using `has()`:

```
td:has(.tooltip1:hover) {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Here is an example:

```css
.td {
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.td:has(.tooltip:hover) {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="td">
  <div class="tooltip">
  sdfksdfksdfksdfksdfsdfksdfk
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. May I some how override for span but not for whole class="tooltip1">?

Comment: The tooltip and span shouldn't need to be overriden as you only have the overflow hidden on the td?

Comment: In case hovered text is too long it should stay hidden only on the tooltip I need full content. For now, I have full content (text) for both

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you want - you want to hide it but not hide it? I don't think that's possible with css as it won't be able to tell if the text is too long.  You would need some js to calculate the length.  Maybe ask a new question with a demonstration now that this has fixed your initial issue?

Comment: For example <div class="tooltip1">Link (this text) should be with hidden, but for tooltip <span>CSS tooltip showing up when your mouse over the link</span> it should be visible. Is it possible? For now it is both visible after overriding

Comment: You would need to wrap the first text in it's own span and then hide the overflow on that but allow the overflow on the tooltip: https://jsfiddle.net/m36210qe/ however this won't work if your tooltip has any styles on it (like border or background colour)